# Jquery Tooltip shows twice

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have a strange jquery Tooltip problem.

The Tooltips works great.

But every time i hover on the Tooltip. 
The same content of the tooltip shows also at the side of the page or at bottom. So i have the tooltip twice.

Hope its clear

This is my code:

```
$( "#card1" ).tooltip({items: "a", content: 'this is my tooltipp' });
```

This is my html code

```
<a id="card1" href="#">tooltipp</a>
```

I use it in Wordpress custom page. I also try to deactivate all Wordpress plugin. But also the same problem.

Can anyone help me what i do wrong?

Here is the screenshot: 
[image: tooltip]

Comment: add some HTML code whatever you have tried.

Comment: thank for your answer i add my html code and updated the post

Comment: Nothing you have posted seems wrong/strange which makes me think you are running `$( "#card1" ).tooltip({items: "a", content: 'this is my tooltipp' }); ` multiple times accidentally.

Comment: yes its strange i cant find a mistake. if i hover on the tooltip i have the content from the tooltip in background again. And the tooltip itself.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the tooltip being displayed twice?

Comment: I have added a screen, the first tip 
disappear after hover on the tip. But the second one still visible till i unload the page.   it is invisible till i first hover on the tip. Any ideas? The same with a picture

Comment: thanks for the help, i solved the problem. I use now a jquery library for tooltips. Then its works.

Answer (score 1):

It shows twice because it add the div
`<div role="log" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></div>`
so you need css of the below class

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
border: 0;
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
height: 1px;
margin: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
}
```

Or you can use

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```